# How to select every table in a Microsoft Word document using VBA Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking for a way (or decent introduction) into how to select every table in a Microsoft Word 2013 Document and autofit the contents. Each table is independent of one another and separated by text.

I have established the following code so far:

```
Sub autofit()

    Selection.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitContent)

End Sub
```

Which works for individual tables and every column in said table, I understand the format of the "for loop", but would like a nudge to how to transform my individual selection to the entire document.

This is my first post so apologies for any conventions I have missed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its pretty trivial to loop them all;

```
Dim t As Table
For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
    t.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent
Next
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you, the bit I wasn't aware of was the ActiveDocument. Basic I know, but I'm completely new to VBA.